# Delay/Pause game while displaying countdown 3,2,1 go

Tags: unity, c#

I have already a running script of countdown and it works fine , the problem is that I want to pause or delay the game while the countdown is displaying, the moment countdown finished the player is already dead. Here is my code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;


public class jb : MonoBehaviour {
    private string countdown = "";    
    private bool showCountdown = false;
    public AudioSource noise1;
    public AudioSource noise2; 
    public Sprite sprite2;
    public Vector2 jump = new Vector2 (0,300);
    private SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer; 
    void Start () {
        //GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = Vector2.right * speed;
        StartCoroutine(getReady());

        spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        noise1.GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if(Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        { 
           Vector2 touchPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(jump);
            //noise1.GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
        }

        Vector2 screen_position = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint (transform.position);
        if(screen_position.y > Screen.height || screen_position.y < 0)
        {
            noise1.GetComponent<AudioSource>().Stop();
            noise2.GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
            StartCoroutine(Die());
        }

    }




    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D det)
    {
        noise1.GetComponent<AudioSource>().Stop();
        noise2.GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
        StartCoroutine(Die());

    }



    IEnumerator Die(){
        PlayerPrefs.SetString( "previousLevel", SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name );
        spriteRenderer.sprite = sprite2;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (2);
        SceneManager.LoadScene("score");
     }


    IEnumerator getReady()    
    {
        showCountdown = true;    

        countdown = "3";    
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (1);  

        countdown = "2";    
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (1);

        countdown = "1";    
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (1);

        countdown = "GO";    
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (1);

        showCountdown = true;
        countdown = "";  
    }

    void OnGUI ()
    {
        if (showCountdown)
        {    
            GUI.color = Color.red;    
            GUI.Box ( new Rect (Screen.width / 2 - 100, 50, 200, 175), "GET READY");

            // display countdown    
            GUI.color = Color.white;    
            GUI.Box (new Rect (Screen.width / 2 - 90, 75, 180, 140), countdown);
        }    
    }
}
```

what can I do to pause the game? I tried invoke (by creating another function and copying everything over there) in update call but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added a simple boolean value to your code: `started`.

At the start, it's false so `Update()` doesn't update the game.
When the countdown finishes, we set it to true so `Update()` can update.

Also, you need to make your player's `Rigidbody2D` unable to move by making it `kinematic` in the `Start()` method:

`GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().isKinematic = true;`

and then set it to `false` after the countdown :)

```
public class jb : MonoBehaviour {
    private string countdown = "";    
    private bool showCountdown = false;
    public AudioSource noise1;
    public AudioSource noise2; 
    public Sprite sprite2;
    public Vector2 jump = new Vector2 (0,300);
    private SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer; 


    bool started = false;


    void Start () {
        //GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = Vector2.right * speed;
        StartCoroutine(getReady());

        spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        noise1.GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();

        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().isKinematic = true;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if(!started) return;

        if(Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        { 
           Vector2 touchPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(jump);
            //noise1.GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
        }

        Vector2 screen_position = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint (transform.position);
        if(screen_position.y > Screen.height || screen_position.y < 0)
        {
            noise1.GetComponent<AudioSource>().Stop();
            noise2.GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
            StartCoroutine(Die());
        }

    }




    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D det)
    {
        noise1.GetComponent<AudioSource>().Stop();
        noise2.GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
        StartCoroutine(Die());

    }



    IEnumerator Die(){
        PlayerPrefs.SetString( "previousLevel", SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name );
        spriteRenderer.sprite = sprite2;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (2);
        SceneManager.LoadScene("score");
     }


    IEnumerator getReady()    
    {
        showCountdown = true;    

        countdown = "3";    
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (1);  

        countdown = "2";    
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (1);

        countdown = "1";    
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (1);

        countdown = "GO";    
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (1);

        showCountdown = true;
        countdown = "";  

        started = true;
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().isKinematic = false;
    }

    void OnGUI ()
    {
        if (showCountdown)
        {    
            GUI.color = Color.red;    
            GUI.Box ( new Rect (Screen.width / 2 - 100, 50, 200, 175), "GET READY");

            // display countdown    
            GUI.color = Color.white;    
            GUI.Box (new Rect (Screen.width / 2 - 90, 75, 180, 140), countdown);
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope it's not working :(

Comment: Please explain what's happenning in-game.

Comment: It;s flappy bird sort of game, a bit altered but the basic idea is same, user touch screen to keep the player in the air. So when I play the click button on main menu I want to show the countdown first with the game behind the countdown box paused but right now when I press the play button there is a countdown box infront and behind the player falls down (because the game is not paused

Comment: Aw, I get it. You have a `Rigidbody` on the player! :) Let me edit the code.

Comment: Check it out now!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66017/discussion-between-spectre-and-melissa).